# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected value parameter count to be higher: rememberNavController()

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am getting `IllegalStateException` while accessing navController instance in Jetpack Compose. Please check the exception below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 2. expected value parameter count to be higher: rememberNavController()
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerParamTransformer.withComposerParamIfNeeded(ComposerParamTransformer.kt:234)
    at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.lower.ComposerParamTransformer$copyWithComposerParam$2$3.visitCall(ComposerParamTransformer.kt:573)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitCall(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrCallImpl.accept(IrCallImpl.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression.transform(IrExpression.kt:33)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.transformChildren(IrVariableImpl.kt:81)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:102)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.accept(IrVariableImpl.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElement$DefaultImpls.transform(IrElement.kt:32)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.IrElementBase.transform(IrElementBase.kt:19)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody.transformChildren(IrBody.kt:62)
...
```

My `MainActivity` code looks like this,

```
setContent {
    MyAndroidAppTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
        ) {
            val navController = rememberNavController()
            NavigateTo(navController = navController, destination = "splash")
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun NavigateTo(navController: NavHostController, destination: String) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = destination) {
        composable("splash") {
            //SplashScreen(navController)
        }
        composable("home") {
            //HomeScreen(navController)
        }
        composable("question") {
            //QuestionScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

My `build.gradle` file configurations are,

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    vmTarget = '1.8'
}
buildFeatures {
    compose true
}
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "1.0.0-beta08"
} 

dependencies {
    ...

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.4.0"
}
```

Comment: What it `NavigateTo`? Please provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I added NavigateTo function to the code,

Comment: [Minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) means that after I copy your code into my project, I can reproduce your problem to help you. Your code still has `SplashScreen`, `HomeScreen` and `QuestionScreen`, which I do not have.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I just commented out those lines, I hope you will be able to check the issue now.

Comment: So it can be reproduced with blank navigation? Most probably it's related to package versions. You're using outdated Compose version, check out if the issue is reproducible with the latest stable one, which is **1.1.0** ATM

Comment: It worked with compose version 1.0.0